# Intersection of final lines

Tags: java, math, line

I have a simple Point object

```
public class Point {
private double x;
private double y;
}
```

and simple Line object

```
public class Line {
private Point start;
private Point end;
}
```

Now I need to find the intersection of two lines, and it's not that simple because the lines have start point and end point....

```
public boolean isIntersecting(Line other) {
....
}

public Point intersectionWith(Line other) {
.....
```

Any ideias?

Comment: This feels like it's pretty much entirely a maths problem - there's no sign that the programming is the problem here. There are *loads* of pages on the internet about the maths of finding out whether lines intersect. Have you looked at any yet? What problems have you run into? At the moment, this question at least *looks* like you haven't done nearly enough research.

Comment: Learn the algorithm to check whether two line segments are intersecting and try to implement it by code. If you have any problem while implementation, you may ask it here.

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/geometry-concepts-line-intersection-and-its-applications/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem instead of programming

Answer (score 0):

First， I think you mean line segment， line has no start and end.
Then,
take start points and end points into equation y = kx + b;
you would get (k1, b1) and (k2, b2),

if k1 == k2 and b1 != b2
  two lines are parallel

if k1 == k2 and b1 == b2
  two lines are same line

if k1 != k2
using y=k1x+b1 and y=k2x+b2 to get point of the intersection(x, y)

finally compare (x, y) with start points and end points to see if there is a intersection.